# PHP Echo multiple select queries

Tags: php, mysql

I usually use the following way to `echo` for the following query

```
$select_time = mysql_query("SELECT submit_time FROM `table` WHERE field_name='user-email' and field_value='test'");
$fetch_time = mysql_fetch_array($select_time);
echo $fetch_time['submit_time'];
```

Can, anyone tell me how to echo each values in the below scenario

```
$select_brands = mysql_query("SELECT max(if(`field_name`='brand-name', `field_value`, null )) AS 'brand-name', max(if(`field_name`='brand-email', `field_value`, null )) AS 'brand-email', max(if(`field_name`='brand-phone', `field_value`, null )) AS 'brand-phone', max(if(`field_name`='brand-manager', `field_value`, null )) AS 'brand-manager' FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE `form_name` = 'Add brands' GROUP BY `submit_time` ORDER BY `submit_time` DESC LIMIT 0,100");
$fetch_branddetails = mysql_fetch_array($select_brands);
```

I need to echo brand-name, brand-email, brand-manager and brand-phone but stuck with syntax how to write the echo statement for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very simple

```
$fetch_branddetails['brand-name']
```

or

```
$fetch_branddetails[0]
```

for brand name same goes for other columns

Answer (score 2):

you need a `for` cycle because you select multiple rows

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($fetch_branddetails); $i ++) { // because you select with LIMIT 0,100 so its max 100 rows
    echo $fetch_branddetails['brand-name'] . $fetch_branddetails['brand-email'] . $fetch_branddetails['brand-manager'] . $fetch_branddetails['brand-phone'] . "\n";
}
```

concatenate php strings with `.`. `"\n"` for new line

or simply use [printf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) `printf ($fetch_branddetails)`;